# Trigger click on after find() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following code traverse through DOM and search for particular A tag that previously have attached event handler. When I found A tag(element) I do a click. This code is correct and works.

```
$('#Content_' + elementid).parents('li').map(function () {
    var expanderId = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
    $('#' + expanderId).click();
});
```

But I want to simplify code with this line but nothing happens.

```
$(this).find('a').click();
```

I also try this

```
$(this).find('a').get(0).click();
```

and this without any success.

Where is the problem? What I'm missing?

Comment: Why `map` if you're not mapping anything?

Comment: Do you have duplicate IDs? If you do, it could explain something.

Comment: If I set foreach following error occurs: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'foreach'

Comment: @JanDvorak - I don't have duplicate IDs.

Comment: @elclanrs - Sorry, each. I set each now.

Comment: Do you have `a`s that might not like to be clicked?

Comment: `get(0)` returns a DOM element. Try `eq(0)`

Comment: @JanDvorak - Works with eq(0). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try wrapping found element in `jQuery` like:

```
var l = $(this).find("a").get(0);
$(l).trigger("click");
```

You can see a working <kbd>**[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/3MGJz/)**</kbd>

Comment: Nope. This error occurs Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'trigger' of undefined.
But works with eq(0).

Comment: 1.9.0. Works when I take jQuery object (use eq, no get).

Comment: @user2034092 `... .get(0).trigger ...` will _not_ work, and was _not_ suggested. Is that what you've tried?

Comment: @JanDvorak - I tried solution above - doesn't work. When I replace get with eq than works my and solution above (from TheVillageIdiot).